# Trying to change the attributes of a Cell's Comment object. The macro generated by Excel does not work

Tags: excel, vba

I want to change the attributes of the text inside in Cell's  Comment object. The automatically generated macro that Excel produced does not work. When running that macro I get the error "Object doesn't support this property or method". I fixed this by changing ".ShapeRange" to ".Shape". Next the error "Object doesn't support this action" was produce by "TextFrame2". 
I am providing the following 2 procedures of code. The first is the original the second is my attempt to solve the problem. However my code is generating the error "Method 'TextFrame' of object 'Shape' failed".

```
Sub OriginalMacro()

    Range("H25").Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleWidth 3.3647051779, msoFalse,   msoScaleFromTopLeft
    Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 1.3800319525, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
    With Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(2, 322).Font
        .NameComplexScript = "Times New Roman"
        .NameFarEast = "Times New Roman"
        .Name = "Times New Roman"
    End With
    Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(2, 322).Font.Size = 12
    Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(2, 322).Font.Bold = _
        msoTrue
    Range("H25").Comment.Text Text:= _
        "Simply place positive numbers in any of the cells from G26 thru G43 directly above the cell that displays the total amount just to the right of the word ""Total;"". They will be added together and dispa"
    Range("H25").Comment.Text Text:= _
        "yed in the cell next to the word ""Total:"". " & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(10) & "If you want to subtract a number simply place a negative sign in front of it." & Chr(10) & "" _
        , Start:=200
    Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 1.1283545656, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
    Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleWidth 1.0731088187, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
    Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleWidth 1.0473934127, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
    Range("E32").Select
End Sub

Sub FormatCalcComment()

    Range("H25").Select
    Range("H25").Comment.Visible = True
    Range("H25").Comment.Shape.ScaleWidth 3.605455577, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
    Range("H25").Comment.Shape.ScaleHeight 1.3080804104, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
    'Range("H25").Comment.Select

    Range("H25").Comment.Shape.Select

    '*********The following line generates the error.**********
    Range("H25").Comment.Shape.TextFrame.Characters(1, 323).Font.Name = "Times New Roman"

        With Range("H25").Comment.Shape.TextFrame.Characters(1, 323).Font
            .NameComplexScript = "Times New Roman"
            .NameFarEast = "Times New Roman"
            .Name = "Times New Roman"
        End With

    Range("H25").Comment.Shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 323).Font.Size = 12
    Range("H25").Comment.Shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 323).Font.Bold = _
        msoTrue
    Range("H25").Comment.Text Text:= _
        "Simply place positive numbers in any of the cells from G26 thru G43 directly above the cell that displays the total amount just to the right of the word ""Total;"". They will be added together and displ"
    Range("H25").Comment.Text Text:= _
        "ayed in the cell next to the word ""Total:"". " & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(10) & "If you want to subtract a number simply place a negative sign in front of it." & Chr(10) & "" _
        , Start:=200
    Range("H25").Comment.Shape.ScaleWidth 1.055297049, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
    Range("H25").Comment.Shape.ScaleHeight 1.2445311296, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
    Range("H26").Select
End Sub
```

Should be Bold faced and changed to New Times Roman. And the frame resized to fit.

Comment: Are you updating the entire text content of the comment, or just a part of it?  The `Characters` collection is only really useful up to about 255 characters, but you don't need it if you're updating the full content.

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 0):

## A Small Comment Study

- I couldn't find anything except the `AutoSize` property which will
  resize to the longest row of text, so you will have to write the text
  e.g. 40 characters maximally per line.
- To place the comment, use the properties of the cell range (`Top`,
  `Height`, `Left` and `Width`) to adjust the same properties of the
  comment particularly the `Top` and `Left` properties, because the
  other will be changed by `AutoSize`.

[image]

### The Code

```
Sub CommentExample()

    Const cSheet As String = "Sheet1"
    Const cStrRange As String = "H25"
    Const Sep As String = vbLf
    Const cMargin As Single = 5

    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim CommEx As Comment
    Dim str1 As String

    Set Cell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSheet).Range(cStrRange)

    ' Look in the Immediate Window
    With Cell
        str1 = "Cell 'Area' Properties"
        str1 = str1 & Sep & Space(2) & "Top = " & .Top
        str1 = str1 & Sep & Space(2) & "Height = " & .Height
        str1 = str1 & Sep & Space(2) & "Left = " & .Left
        str1 = str1 & Sep & Space(2) & "Width = " & .Width
        Debug.Print str1
    End With

    Set CommEx = Cell.Comment

    If CommEx Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No Comment in Cell '" & cStrRange & "'."
        Cell.AddComment
        Set CommEx = Cell.Comment
    End If

    With CommEx
        .Visible = True
        With .Shape.TextFrame.Characters
            .Delete
            With .Font
                .Name = "Times New Roman"
                .Size = 12
                .Bold = True
            End With
        End With

        ' Text Width:   "======================================== "
        .Text _
                        "Simply place positive numbers in any of " _
                & Sep & "the cells from G26 thru G43 directly " _
                & Sep & "above the cell that displays the total " _
                & Sep & "amount just to the right of the word " _
                & Sep & """Total"". They will be added together " _
                & Sep & "and displayed in the cell next to the " _
                & Sep & "word ""Total""." _
                & Sep _
                & Sep & "If you want to subtract a number simply " _
                & Sep & "place a negative sign in front of it."
        ' Text Width:   "======================================== "

        With .Shape

           ' Look in the Immediate Window
            str1 = "Comment 'Area' Properties (Before AutoSize)"
            str1 = str1 & Sep & Space(2) & "Top = " & .Top
            str1 = str1 & Sep & Space(2) & "Height = " & .Height
            str1 = str1 & Sep & Space(2) & "Left = " & .Left
            str1 = str1 & Sep & Space(2) & "Width = " & .Width
            Debug.Print str1

            With .TextFrame
                ' To use margins you have to set AutoMargins to False.
                .AutoMargins = False
                .MarginBottom = cMargin
                .MarginLeft = cMargin
                .MarginRight = cMargin
                .MarginTop = cMargin
                ' Depending on vbLf, the Autosize property will 'resize to fit'.
                .AutoSize = True
            End With

            ' Look in the Immediate Window
            str1 = "Comment 'Area' Properties (After AutoSize)"
            str1 = str1 & Sep & Space(2) & "Top = " & .Top
            str1 = str1 & Sep & Space(2) & "Height = " & .Height
            str1 = str1 & Sep & Space(2) & "Left = " & .Left
            str1 = str1 & Sep & Space(2) & "Width = " & .Width
            Debug.Print str1

            With .TextFrame
                ' Look in the Immediate Window
                str1 = "Margins"
                str1 = str1 & Sep & Space(2) & "MarginBottom = " & .MarginBottom
                str1 = str1 & Sep & Space(2) & "MarginLeft = " & .MarginLeft
                str1 = str1 & Sep & Space(2) & "MarginRight = " & .MarginRight
                str1 = str1 & Sep & Space(2) & "MarginTop = " & .MarginTop
                Debug.Print str1
            End With

        End With

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the sub below will solve part of your problem. Call it with code like, `SetComment Cells(1, 1), "Comment text", True` which would append "Comment text" to text already existing in a comment in cell A1. Define *Concat* as False to replace existing text.

```
Sub SetComment(Cell As Range, _
               Optional ByVal Txt As String, _
               Optional ByVal Concat As Boolean)
    ' 12 Jul 2018
    ' deletes existing comment if Txt = "" and Concat = False

    Dim Cmt As String

    With Cell
        On Error Resume Next
        Cmt = .Comment.Text
        .Comment.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Concat Then
            If Len(Cmt) Then Cmt = Cmt & Chr(10)
        Else
            Cmt = ""
        End If

        Txt = Cmt & Txt
        If Len(Txt) Then .AddComment Cmt & Txt
    End With
End Sub
```